# Bibtex for United Nations Agenda 2030

Tags: bibtex

I realize this is borderline off topic, but I don't know who else to ask.

I need a bibtex entry for the [United Nations Agenda 2030](https://sustainabledevelopment.un.org/post2015/transformingourworld) and I can't for the life of me find one. I don't even know how to write one. What is the document type? Who is the author?

Yet, it seems there should be a standardized way to cite it.

Comment: If you want to cite the website https://sustainabledevelopment.un.org/post2015/transformingourworld you'll probably be OK with the document type `@online` (or `@misc` if your style doesn't support it), then `title = {Transforming Our World: The 2030 Agenda for Sustainable Development},` (so far so good), for the author you can put `author ={{United Nations}},` or `author = {{United Nations General Assembly}},`. The year of publication would be `2015`. If you then put the URL into the `url` field (or `howpublished` if your style doesn't support `url`), you're probably good.

Comment: If you want to cite the more formal https://www.un.org/ga/search/view_doc.asp?symbol=A/RES/70/1&Lang=E and reference some of the more technical things like the resolution number *A/RES/70/1*, a good solution will depend on the style you use. Most styles don't support an entry type for legal documents, treaties, resolutions or laws, but it may be possible to get acceptable output with a type like `@techreport` or with `@online`/`@misc` and the `note` field.

Comment: If you want to cite https://sustainabledevelopment.un.org/content/documents/21252030%20Agenda%20for%20Sustainable%20Development%20web.pdf, `@book` might also be an option, but of course `@online`/`@misc` would still be fine. Sometimes the right entry type is a matter of details and taste.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using this:

```
@misc{Agenda2023,
author = {United Nations, Department of Economic and Social Affairs - Sustainable Development},
title = {Transforming our world: the 2030 Agenda for Sustainable Development},
pages = {16301},
ISBN = {A/RES/70/1},
URL = {https://sdgs.un.org/2030agenda},
year = {2015},
type = {General Assembly}
}
```